# Can you name this square root algorithm on an unsigned integer through the manipulation of the binary number?

Tags: algorithms, binary

Apparently this algorithm is well known.

The algorithm will build the square root answer bit by bit starting from the left-most bit to the last.

Let's say we will support squaring up to a 8 bit unsigned integer for simplicity.

let **res** be result

let **x** be 8 bit unsigned integer

let **n** be the nth bit in the result where the 0th bit is the last bit.

```
set res to 0
for nth bit from 3 down to 0
    change the nth bit of the res to 1
    if res * res > x then: <- The Comparison
         restore the nth bit back to 0
return res
```

The return result will be a 4 bit unsigned integer

For Example: Finding the square root of 4

(see image)
[image]

Is this perhaps the Digit by Digit Calculation: Binary Numeral System (base 2)? [Wiki Link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here.

Comment: I would describe it as optimized binary search.

Comment: What is shown in the question is *a* digit-by-digit calculation of the square root (I would claim not a particular fast one, and therefore of little practical use). What is shown at the Wiki link is the classical longhand digit-by-digit square rooting method based on the binomial theorem, which goes back to the Middle Ages (possibly Fibonacci's "Liber Abaci"?) and until a few decades ago, was taught to high-school students.

Answer (score 3):

i might call it **successive approximation** or maybe [binary search to invert a monotonic function](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/).

if you are able to perform a function `f(x)`, and if you know that `f(x)` is strictly monotonic (strictly increasing or strictly decreasing) in the domain of `x` that is salient, then you can always invert `f(x)` to whatever finite degree of precision you want with this binary search.  one iteration for every bit you need in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's essentially the same algorithm described at the article that you linked.

The main difference is your pseudo-code's use of multiplication, which costs more than what can be done, as the same article points out, "... the operations needed to compute ... e * e can be replaced with faster bit shift operations."

'HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, if it is given that `X == Y^2` (a reformulation of `sqrt(X) == Y`), and you would like to solve `(N*N*X + m) == (N*Y + k)^2` for `k` where the value of `N` is fixed for the entire algorithm, you can simply substitute values into `k` from `k = 0, 1, ..., N-1` and compare the magnitude between the left hand side (which is fixed) and the right hand side (which depend on the value substituted into `k`).

For `N = 2`, the possible value of `k` is simply `0, 1` so that it reduces to a binary search.